# Improving line extraction from Opencv HoughLinesP

Tags: opencv, image-processing, grayscale, hough-transform

I am using `HoughLinesP` to extract lines from grayscale image.

Below is my psudo code.

```
threshold(img_tmp,bin_img,30,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
Canny(bin_img, canny_img, 50, 255, 3);
vector<Vec4i> tmp_lines;
HoughLinesP(canny_img,tmp_lines, 1, CV_PI/360,10, 10, 1);
```

As can be seen in zoomed image single edge (i.e single line in image) is returning more than one line. 16,22 and 0,28 and 10,11 and 23,18,24 lines correspond to single line.

How can i get single line for single edge, any suggestions ?

**Input image:**

[image]

**Extracted lines**
[image]

**Issue**

[image]

thanks.

Comment: The problem is you are using canny edge detector which finds edges on both sides of each line. It works well with natural images and finds the boundary between two objects/parts, but it is nut suitable for your kind of input. I would try thresholding the image, cleaning it a bit (using morphology), invert (so that boundaries are white) and send it to Hough

Comment: For cleaning i tried dilation and erosion but the result is same.

Comment: Did you run canny? the main issue is not to run any kind of edge detection or gradient operation. you can use a Canny-like non maxima suppression for cleaning (you'll have to slightly blur the image before doing that)

Comment: I tried thresholding-->erosion-->dilation-->canny--> hough but the result is not improved. I will try blur before doing canny.

Answer (score 0):

Again, canny or any edge detection algorithm is not suitable for this kind of input since the lines are basically edges. Try applying some kind of non maxima suppression on the input followed by Hough lines without edge detection of any kind.